# SSRS 2005 Saving Report Parameters

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I've been working with SSRS 2005 reports for a little while now, and I've had a few requests come across asking for individual users to be able to save the parameters they use for the next time they run the report. Is this feasible? Is it a part of the "My Reports" role? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll have to stop using the built-in UI and build your own report front-end to do that. I have always used RS this way and it is not all that complicated.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. The one thing I don't know is how to properly integrate with the AD security. Any thoughts or pointers?

Comment: If you use the ReportViewer control (http://www.gotreportviewer.com/), you don't need to integrate (but you have to do a bit more coding). If you have to use the server, you could use the Web Service interface, or proxy requests using the URL interface. I have always avoided AD integration with RS.

Comment: I just remembered, I actually did an implementation of RS 1.0 with a Java proxy (see http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-01-2005/jw-0110-sqlrs.html).

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if that can be done using the report manager, but you could always use URL parameters and pass through that way, then just give them the link to follow which will take them to their report (or render it as a PDF or other format if you wish) and already have the parameters passed in.

Here is a link that will take you to a lot of MSDN documentation about [URL Access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153586.aspx) for your Reports.